# MS Access link tables returning only first row multiple times

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm using MS Access 2013, my database is all linked tables attaching to an Oracle 11 database.  I have 14 linked tables, all linked to views in Oracle.  I've created Queries for each linked table and used those to create my forms.  I have one main form where I do an employee search and that drives the remaining forms and their individual queries.  At first the queries worked as expected and showing appropriate data for each employee.  Now as I've gone in and made changes and recreated the links, the data that is returned is not working.

When I search for an Employee "Bob" and look at "Bobs" Job History, I expect to see 24 rows of job history.  Now it will show the first record of the job history duplicated 24 times.

When I execute the views in Oracle, I see. the correct information

Comment: Please provide enough code to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Access needs a primary key in the Oracle table (or view!) to display the data properly. The problem you are having indicates that Access was not able to recognize a usable primary key in the table.

For tables, make sure the table has primary key and check if the datatype is usable by Access. Access can only use 32bit integers. Bigger numbers will be treated as double, which is bad for primary keys due to floating point inaccuracies.

While Oracle-Views do not have a primary key, they still need a field (or combination of fields) that Access can use to uniquely identify records. When linkin a View, Access will prompt you for this unique key. Choosing a non unique field will result in the problem you are describing.

Open the linked Oracle-Tables/View in Access in DesignView and check, which primary keys Access is using for those tables.